# In VC++ PPL, how do I create a task-returning method that returns synchronously?

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, task-parallel-library, ppl

Consider the following C# code:

```
async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
 if (m_f)
   return;
 await DoSomethingInternalAsync();
}
```

What the compiler turns this into is a task returning call where if m_f is true, the task completes immediately and if not, it "delegates" the async operation to DoSomethingInternalAsync().

Now, how do I do this in c++? The code should look something like this:

```
task<void> DoSomethingAsync()
{
if (m_f)
   return [[What do I return here so the task is complete (.then called immediately)?!]];
return DoSomethingInternalAsync();
}
```

Edit1: In C#, I can use a TaskCompletionSource<> to do the same thing, but w/o using the async keyword - essentially create a completed Task.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another way to do this is [task_from_result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237326.aspx). You can use `concurrency::task_from_result()` for `task<void>` methods and `concurrency::task_from_result(theReturnValue)` for `task<T>` methods. I believe this is new starting in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Got it.. This will create an empty task:

```
concurrency::create_task([]{});
```